# Why does MAX return the wrong value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

From table by query

```sql
select item from items;
```

I selected all existing values:

```
0.1
0.54
5.13
9.38
892576.15
62612159.13
```

Type of column "Item" is text

And I also able to retrieve maximum. Obviously, that for this sample, maximum is 62612159.13

But query

```
select max(item) from items;
```

return  "9.38"-value.

I suspect, that problem in data type. I tried to cast selected values (before applying max) to other data formats: decimal, real, double precision, but without success.

For example, when I cast values to real, it return me "0.1,   0.54"-

Comment: Sounds as if that column is defined as `text` or `varchar`. Using `decimal` or real should not show that behaviour

Comment: Yes, I forget to claim: column is defined as text.  I'll update my Ask

Comment: `max(item::decimal)` should work then. But the correct solution is to change the column's data type. **Never** store numbers (or `date` or `timestamp` values) in `text` columns.

Comment: For text, 9.38 **is** the largest value (assuming a collation that doesn't apply numeric ordering).

Comment: Please show the SQL you used when you tried to cast. Given the data shown, there doesn't seem to be any way for `max()` to return a combination of values like "0.1, 0.54".